# iPython 3.5.2 lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, ipython

I have created a list size 12, ex: `V[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11]`
How do I return only the last 10 digits `[2:11]`? Also what if the list had n variables, I tried `V[2,:]`, but I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`.

Comment: The last 10 digits is `V[-10:]`. I'm not sure how `n` is supposed to be used here, but you can do `V[2:]` if that's what you mean. You can read the basics on slicing in the std tutorial https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the last `x` elements of a list, you need to use a negative index in your slice.

```
>>> numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> numbers[-5:]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

As for the error you mentioned, it looks like you have a stray comma after the 2, which makes 2 the first element in a tuple. Take out the comma and it should be a valid slice.